Is my solution really valid?
Reduce the PDE into canonical form $x^2y^2u_{xx} +2xyu_{xy}+ u_{yy} = 0.$
My solution goes like this:
The characteristic equation is, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy\pm \sqrt{ 4x^2y^2-4x^2y^2}}{2x^2y^2}=\frac{1}{xy}.$$
This means, $$ydy=\frac{dx}{x}\implies \log x-\frac{y^2}{2}=c,$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.
Let $\xi=\log x-\frac{y^2}{2},\eta=y.$
This means,
$u_x=u_{\xi}\xi_x+u_{\eta}\eta_x=\frac{u_{\xi}}{x},$
$u_{xx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}[u_{\xi\xi}-u_{\xi}],$
$u_{yy}=-2yu_{\eta \xi}+u_{\eta \eta}-u_{\xi}+y^2u_{\xi\xi},$
$u_{xy}=-\frac yxu_{\xi\xi}+\frac{u_{\xi\eta}}{x}.$
Substituting the values of $u_{xx},u_{xy},u_{yy}$ in the given PDE we have,
$u_{\eta\eta}=(1+y^2)u_{\xi}.$
This means, $u_{\eta\eta}=(1+\eta^2)u_{\xi}.$

However, the answer given in the book is, $u_{ηη}+(ξ/η^2)u_ξ = 0.$
But I am unable to find any mistake in my solution. I went through it several times, but it seems correct to me. Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.
